# How to determine moment when WebView (or View) ready to screenshot?

Tags: android, view, screenshot

I have a problem, I need to make screenshots of `WebView` in different sizes at once (in portrait and lanscape) and make it fast.

So, to make a screenshot I change `WebView`'s layout params, and call `invalidate()`, as you know it works asynchronously and will take effect at some moment later.

How can I **determine moment** when `WebView` applied new layout params and ready to make screenshot?